# Fetch data with Repository Pattern after orientation change

Tags: android, repository-pattern

I have a question related to orientation change. 
In my application I use `MVP` + `Retrofit` + `RxKotlin` and `Repository pattern`. On app open data are downloaded from API through repository - everything is good. After I rotate device I wonder how should I fetch data without asking API again. Should I save data to `DB` after first download or there should I do something different?

Comment: Have you tried using a fragment inside your activity, then calling `setRetainInstance(true)`, and then making your API call only in `onCreate()`? Using a Fragment, with `setRetainInstance(true)` will only make the API call when the Fragment is first created.  After, when you do a rotation, it will not call the Fragment's `onCreate()` method, but will retain the data you retrieved from the API call the first time.

Comment: @DavidVelasquez I'm fetching data from `Activity` level and then send it to fragments in `ViewPager`, so basically that wouldn't work. Maybe I will change my approach and move data fetch to `Fragments` level. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle on my app where I'm also using the ViewModel + Repository pattern:

- First, make sure your Repository object has Application scope so it also survives the destruction of fragments and activities.
- Since your ViewModel will survive screen rotations, keep a cache of the fetched data in-memory in your ViewModel. For example: if you make your UI observe a LiveData in your ViewModel, and you set the value in the LiveData when the Repository returns, the LiveData will keep the last emitted value, so when your UI subscribes again you will get the data right away.
- And, since your fragment will get re-created, you will call again fetch, but in your ViewModel, you can save and check if you already made a network call with the same parameters and URL and ignore it. (Note: don't put a filter if savedInstanceState is non-null to avoid re-fetching, this is not always true).

That's an idea, you can adaptive in your own way.

My main point is that your ViewModel is there to help you survive any type of configuration changes without re-fetching data or losing the state of your screen. Try always to make your ViewModel stateful and your UI stateless, so your UI's only responsibility is to reflect whatever state your ViewModel has.

Comment: problem here is that I don't work with `ViewModel` and `LiveData` so I can't use these tools.

Comment: @Janekxyz in that case you can just save a variable cache in your ViewModel and return it again if the UI asks for the same data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make the API calls in the ViewPager Fragments, and you shouldn't do it in your Activity either. Instead, you can add a Fragment within your main Activity. That fragment will be your parent Fragment. In the parent Fragment's `onCreate()` is where you make the API call. Then you create the ViewPager with the individual child Fragments within your parent Fragment. Make sure, that when you create your ViewPager adapter you pass in the instance of the child FragmentManager like this:

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        API.getData(); //Make API call; has to be done on a separate thread using an AsyncTask or an IntentService. When Data is successfully retrieved, save it to a field in this Fragment.
        //Create ViewPager adapter here like this:
        viewPagerAdapter = new MainVPAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); //<- important
    }
}
```